# how to fetch a value from a dataFrame cell to fill in value at another location?

Tags: python, pandas

I  have the following DataFrame:

```
ID | Parent ID | Direction
1  |   0       | North
2  |   1       | South
3  |   1       | West
4  |   0       | East
```

I want to write a function that will change the direction for all rows that have a non-zero 'Parent ID' to the Direction of the corresponding parent.

Desired Result:

```
ID | Parent ID | Direction
1  |   0       | North     #Ignore because Parent Id = 0
2  |   1       | North     #Changed to Direction of Parent Id = 1
3  |   1       | North     #Changed to Direction of Parent Id = 1
4  |   0       | East      #Ignore because Parent Id = 0
```

Here is the code to create the above sample dataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'ID' : [1,2,3,4],
             'Parent ID' : [0,1,1,0],
             'Direction' : ['North', 'South','West','East']})
```

I tried writing a function and calling map on Parent ID but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
to_replace = df['Parent ID'] != 0
df.loc[to_replace, 'Direction'] = df['Parent ID'][to_replace].map(df.set_index("ID").Direction)    
df
```

[image]